# Deleting item from listView only delete last item not selected element android

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I have a list view that I am able  which depending on the button clicked will populate the list view and will display an appropriate layout. That all works fine.

However what I'm now trying to do is delete the select element from the list view via an alert window using:

`ArrayList.remove(position);`

`ArrayListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Which seems like it should work and I have seen other suggestions when googleing that this is what should be called but instead of deleting the selected element it always deletes the last element from the ListView and I can not figure out why?

My only though is I need to handle something more in my getView() method in my ArrayListAdapter extending baseAdapter but I can't for the life of me find/figure out what that might be?

I  welcome any suggestion or thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ChatRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList());
    private ArrayListAdapter messageArrayListAdapter;
    private Message storeMsgButtonPressedObj;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);


        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        EditText chatMsgEditTextView = findViewById(R.id.msgBox);
        listView.setAdapter(messageArrayListAdapter = new ArrayListAdapter());

        Button sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        Button receivedButton = findViewById(R.id.receivedBtn);


        sendButton.setOnClickListener(Click -> {

            storeMsgButtonPressedObj = new Message(chatMsgEditTextView.getText().toString(), 1);
            messageArrayList.add(storeMsgButtonPressedObj);
            messageArrayListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chatMsgEditTextView.getText().clear();

        });

        receivedButton.setOnClickListener(Click -> {
            storeMsgButtonPressedObj = new Message(chatMsgEditTextView.getText().toString(), 2);
            messageArrayList.add(storeMsgButtonPressedObj);
            messageArrayListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chatMsgEditTextView.getText().clear();

        });


        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener( (AdapterView, View, indexOfViewElement, databaseID) -> {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you want to delete this?");


            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(
                    "The position of your item is: " + indexOfViewElement + "\n" 
                  + "The database id id: " + databaseID
            );


            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (click, arg) -> {

                messageArrayList.remove(indexOfViewElement);
                messageArrayListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", (click, arg) -> { });

            alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
            return true;
        });



    }
    // onCreate() END*****


    private class ArrayListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        //gets current size of array list
        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return messageArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int indexValueOfElement){
            return storeMsgButtonPressedObj.getMsgValue()  /* + indexValueOfElement*/;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int indexValueOfElement){
            return (long) indexValueOfElement;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int indexValueOfElement, View currentView, ViewGroup parent){

            View updateView = currentView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


            if(updateView == null) {

                if(storeMsgButtonPressedObj.getButtonPressed() == 1) {

                    updateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sent, parent, false);

                    TextView tView = updateView.findViewById(R.id.testViewSent);

                    tView.setText( getItem(indexValueOfElement).toString() );
                }

                if(storeMsgButtonPressedObj.getButtonPressed() == 2){

                    updateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_received, parent, false);

                    TextView tView = updateView.findViewById(R.id.textViewReceived);

                    tView.setText( getItem(indexValueOfElement).toString() );
                }
            }


            //return the updated view object
            return updateView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Message Class I wrote to store the String and an int to determine which button was pressed so that the correct layout can be inflated.

```
public class Message {

private String msgValue;
private int buttonPressed;

   Message(){

   }

   Message(String msg, int buttonPressed){

       this.msgValue = msg;
       this.buttonPressed = buttonPressed;
   }

    public String getMsgValue() {
        return msgValue;
    }

    public int getButtonPressed() {
        return buttonPressed;
    }

    public void setMsgValue(String msgValue) {
        this.msgValue = msgValue;
    }

    public void setButtonPressed(int sendReceive) {
        this.buttonPressed = sendReceive;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Adapter class.

I have updated `getItem` and `getView` at little.
As I can see your `getItem` and `getView` was directly using the `storeMsgButtonPressedObj` which is holding the last send or receive the message as per your implementation, it should not be used to create a view or in `getItem` but rather it should have extracted from List holding these values.

```
private class ArrayListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//gets current size of array list
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messageArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int indexValueOfElement) {
    return messageArrayList.get(indexValueOfElement);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int indexValueOfElement) {
    return (long) indexValueOfElement;
}

@Override
public View getView(int indexValueOfElement, View currentView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View updateView = currentView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


    if (updateView == null) {

        if (messageArrayList.get(indexValueOfElement).getButtonPressed() == 1) {

            updateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sent, parent, false);

            TextView tView = updateView.findViewById(R.id.testViewSent);

            tView.setText(getItem(indexValueOfElement).toString());
        }

        if (messageArrayList.get(indexValueOfElement).getButtonPressed() == 2) {

            updateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_received, parent, false);

            TextView tView = updateView.findViewById(R.id.textViewReceived);

            tView.setText(getItem(indexValueOfElement).toString());
        }
    }


    //return the updated view object
    return updateView;
}
}
```